# Remember current month on page reloads using FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io), is it possible to remember which month you're viewing? I have an admin that allows for scheduling, and it would be great to have each page refresh first ask the question, "Which month was the user navigating last? Start with that one."

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't support doing that natively but you could use local storage, cookies, or server-side saving of last date range/view? Getting that info can be done with [getView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/getView/) which returns a [View object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/)

Comment: on the viewRender callback, store the current view in a cookie, or ajax it up to the server, would be my suggestion. Then you can restore it easily when the page reloads, and either inject it as the defaultView and currentDate values into the generated calendar config, or cause it to run the appropriate fullCalendar methods as soon as the calendar initialises to switch the view and date. (I say view as well, so that you can be a bit more flexible, not just month views but any type of view)

Comment: I've used cookies for the view, resource and date which are updated each time any are changed by the user. Whenever the user returns to the page if the cookies have not expired it will use their stored values or if expired then the cookies are recreated with default values.